# How to keep same order on each session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a store in rails. As I'm new to Rails I was following some tutorial on how to create a shopping cart and ordering system.

So right now orders with unique ids are being created and saved by a user, automatically, upon addition of a order_item to a cart on each new session. And this is the issue.

I want order to persist until 30 days passes (the one order that is created first, that is, when first order_item has been added by a user). The problem is next: So if user adds order_items, he creates an order and then logs out and comes back and adds a new order_item to his cart, new order is being created even though there is already his older order saved to database. I want to retrieve that first order.

Can you please tell me how to achieve this?

```
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
    @order.user_id = current_user.id
    @order.save
    session[:order_id] = @order.id

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { flash[:notice] = "ORDER ITEM HAS BEEN ADDED." } 
  end
  end
```

order_item.rb

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :order
  validates_associated :order
  validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
  validate :product_present
  validate :order_present


  before_save :finalize

  def unit_price
    if persisted?
      self[:unit_price]
    else
      product.price
    end
  end

  def total_price
    unit_price * quantity
  end

private
  def product_present
    if product.nil?
      errors.add(:product, "is not valid or is not active.")
    end
  end

  def order_present
    if order.nil?
      errors.add(:order, "is not a valid order.")
    end
  end

  def finalize
    self[:unit_price] = unit_price
    self[:total_price] = quantity * self[:unit_price]
  end


end
```

order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order_status
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :order_items
  validates_length_of :order_items, maximum: 3
  before_create :set_order_status
  before_save :update_subtotal



  def subtotal
    order_items.collect { |oi| oi.valid? ? (oi.quantity * oi.unit_price) : 0 }.sum
  end
private
  def set_order_status
    self.order_status_id = 1
  end

  def update_subtotal
    self[:subtotal] = subtotal
  end



end
```

user.rb

```
has_many :order
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to retrieve that first order.

This line:

> @order = current_order

Where is `current_order` defined?  You want it to find the existing order if present, instead of creating a new one. Something like:

```
 def current_order
    order = Order.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
    if order.nil?
       order = Order.create (...etc)
    end
    order
 end
```

Comment: It is defined in application_controller.rb and it looks like this:  helper_method :current_order   `def current_order
    if !session[:order_id].nil?
      Order.find(session[:order_id])
    else
      Order.new
    end
  end`

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure where `session[:order_id]` is coming from, but maybe you want to change it to `Order.find(session[:order_id]) || Order.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)`.  Did you write this code yourself? Do you know how to program?

Comment: No I haven't write it myself it is from this tutorial: https://richonrails.com/articles/building-a-shopping-cart-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: It's working by leaving only: Order.find_by_user_id(current_user.id) . I understand now. Thank you!!